# How to include sparse points in a ContourPlot if any?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, intersection

I'm working with the following expressions:

$$\left(\frac{1-\tanh (X)}{\tanh (X)+1}\right)^{-k}=\pm\frac{P_2^{(k,-k)}(\tanh (X))}{P_2^{(-k,k)}(\tanh (X))}$$

where $X\in[0,5]$ and $k\in\left[-\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}},\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}}\right]$ exluding $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. I want to obtain an X vs. k plot, so I tried the following:

```
ContourPlot[{((1 - Tanh[X])/(1 + Tanh[X]))^-k == 
   JacobiP[2, k, -k, Tanh[X]]/JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]],
  ((1 - Tanh[X])/(1 + Tanh[X]))^-k == -(JacobiP[2, k, -k, Tanh[X]]/
    JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]])}, {X, 0, 5}, {k, -Sqrt[16/3], Sqrt[
  16/3]}, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Full}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
 ContourStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"+sign", "-sign"}, {0.8, 0.1}], 
 Exclusions -> 
  Flatten[{Table[k == n, {n, -4, 4, 1}], 
    JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]] == 0}]]
```

And I got

[image]

But, since I'm reproducing a plot, I expect to obtain this

[image]

So, I dont know if `ContourPlot` can reach some sparse points to yield something like this

[image]

Comment: The sparse points which you are mentioning are included in the `Exclusions` if I am not mistaken; see what you get for `Exclusions -> Flatten[{Table[k == n, {n, 0, 4, 1}], JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]] == 0}]` Am I confusing myself?

Comment: @bmf The 'Exclusions' part was added to avoid $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and possible $P_2^{(-k,k)}(\tanh (X))=0$ points. It has a 'Table' because this plot is part of a series of plots, in this case $k$ cannot be equal to $-2,-1,0,1$ and 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split the plots and separately specify exclusions:

```
g1 = ContourPlot[{((1 - Tanh[X])/(1 + Tanh[X]))^-k == -(JacobiP[2, 
        k, -k, Tanh[X]]/JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]])}, {X, 0, 
   5}, {k, -Sqrt[16/3], Sqrt[16/3]}, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Full}, 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"-sign"}, {0.8, 0.12}], 
  Exclusions -> 
   Flatten[{k == 1, k == -1, JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]] == 0}]]
g2 = ContourPlot[{((1 - Tanh[X])/(1 + Tanh[X]))^-k == 
    JacobiP[2, k, -k, Tanh[X]]/JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]]}, {X, 0, 
   5}, {k, -Sqrt[16/3], Sqrt[16/3]}, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Full}, 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> Red, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"+sign"}, {0.8, 0.2}], 
  Exclusions -> 
   Flatten[{k == -2, k == 2, k == 0, 
     JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]] == 0}]]
Show[g1, g2]
```

[image]